# Create mulipul jars for different JVMs versions

Tags: java, maven

I'm using JDK 17 and I want to create (and deploy) my package for different JVMs.
my `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jdk-17-compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <release>17</release>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}-jdk17</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jdk-11-compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}-jdk11</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jdk-17-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}-jdk17</classesDirectory>
                <classifier>jdk17</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jdk-11-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}-jdk11</classesDirectory>
                <classifier>jdk11</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For this setup, I'm getting the following error at the `compile` goal:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
> [ERROR] Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
> [INFO] 2 errors
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

What is missing? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just build it with Java 11? You can use a Java 11 jar in Java 17 as well.

Comment: @JFabianMeier because I want the java compiler to compile the code in the most efficient way for each JVM, and in addition, I want to add support for JVM 8, and I know internally the bytecode is different

Comment: what about backward compatibility? i would say the compiler optimizes source code in the best possible way . And all following versions also are built in the best optimized way to also serve preceding versions. If you nonetheless need more efficiency maybe you switch to C or another low level language..

Comment: @RoyAsh I would not do that unless you measured performance and found out that it strongly improves. People usually just compile for the lowest JDK they want to support, in your case Java 8.

Comment: Ok, I understand.. but still, for the sake of better understanding `maven-compiler-plugin`, is it possible in some way?